# bot is removing all messages

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I wrote this script to delete all messages from a specific channel that were not images, but the bot removes all text messages and images.

here is the code:

```js
client.on("message", (message) => {
  let channel = client.channels.get(`642417479708049418`);
  if (message.author.bot) return;
  if (message.member.roles.some(r => ["DEAN!"].includes(r.name))) return;
  if (message.channel.id != channel.id) {
    return
  } else {
    if (message.embeds.length > 0) {
      return
    } else {
      message.channel.send(`${message.author} this channel is for images only`);
      message.delete();
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use MessageAttachments:

```
client.on("message", (message) => {
  let channel = client.channels.get(`642417479708049418`);
  if (message.author.bot) return;
  if (message.member.roles.some(r => ["DEAN!"].includes(r.name))) return;
  if (message.channel.id != channel.id) {
    return
  } else {
    if (message.attachments.size > 0) {
      return
    } else {
      message.channel.send(`${message.author} this channel is for images only`);
      message.delete();
    }
  }
});
```